# Needs add manual approval between the terraform plan and apply task in yamal pipelines

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

trigger:

- none

stages:

- stage: TF_Deploy
  jobs:

  - job: TerraformPlan
    pool:
    name: win18pcpool
    steps:

    - checkout: self
    - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
      displayName: 'Terraform-init'
      inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: 'TF-Infra-Deploy/SRC/Dev'
      backendServiceArm: 'REBUS_POC'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'TF-DEMO'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'hashicorptfelogs'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: 'terraform-test-pipeline'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'
    - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
      displayName: 'Terraform-plan'
      inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: 'TF-Infra-Deploy/SRC/Dev'
      commandOptions: '-out=tfplan'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'REBUS_POC'
  - job: manual_approval
    displayName: 'Manual Approval'
    dependsOn: TerraformPlan
    condition: succeeded('TerraformPlan')
    pool: server
    steps:

    - task: ManualValidation@0
      inputs:
      notifyUsers: ''
      instructions: 'Please review and approve'
      onTimeout: 'resume'

trigger:

- none

stages:

- stage: TF_Deploy
  jobs:

  - job: TerraformPlan
    pool:
    name: win18pcpool
    steps:

    - checkout: self
    - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
      displayName: 'Terraform-init'
      inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: 'TF-Infra-Deploy/SRC/Dev'
      backendServiceArm: 'REBUS_POC'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'TF-DEMO'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'hashicorptfelogs'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: 'terraform-test-pipeline'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'
    - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
      displayName: 'Terraform-plan'
      inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: 'TF-Infra-Deploy/SRC/Dev'
      commandOptions: '-out=tfplan'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'REBUS_POC'
  - job: manual_approval
    displayName: 'Manual Approval'
    dependsOn: TerraformPlan
    condition: succeeded('TerraformPlan')
    pool: server
    steps:

    - task: ManualValidation@0
      inputs:
      notifyUsers: ''
      instructions: 'Please review and approve'
      onTimeout: 'resume'
  - job: TerraformApply
    condition: succeeded('manual_approval')
    dependsOn: manual_approval
    pool:
    name: win18pcpool
    steps:

    - checkout: self
    - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
      inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'apply'
      workingDirectory: 'TF-Infra-Deploy/SRC/Dev'
      commandOptions: 'tfplan -auto-approve'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'REBUS_POC'

Answer (score 0):

According to this [blog1](https://n4stack.io/2021/06/21/azure-devops-terraform-pipeline-with-checkov-approvals/) you can make use of manual validation task and approve the validation via User email and run your terraform apply task further like below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: "approveTerraform"
  displayName: "Terraform - Manual Approval"
  dependsOn: []
  condition: |
    and(
      succeeded(),
      eq(dependencies.planTerraform.outputs['TerraformJobs.setvar.HAS_DESTROY_CHANGES'], 'true')
    )
  jobs:
    - job: "waitForValidation"
      displayName: "Wait > Wait for manual approval"
      pool:
        name: "server"
      timeoutInMinutes: 4000 
      steps:
        - task: ManualValidation@0
          timeoutInMinutes: 1300
          inputs:
            notifyUsers: |
              xxxxi@outlook.com
            instructions: "Approve"
            onTimeout: "reject"

    - job: "TerraformApprove"
      displayName: "Terraform > install, init & apply"
      dependsOn: "waitForValidation"
      steps:
        - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
          inputs:
            terraformVersion: "4.0.0"
          displayName: "Install > terraform"
          

        - task: TerraformCLI@0
          inputs:
            command: "init"
            backendType: "azurerm"
            backendServiceArm: "xxx subscription (xxxxxxb4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7)"
            ensureBackend: true
            backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: "valleyrg43"
            backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: "valleystrg54"
            backendAzureRmContainerName: 'data'
            backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'
            workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

        - task: TerraformCLI@0
          inputs:
            command: "apply"
            environmentServiceName: "xxx subscription (xxxx-xxxxxxx-b4fd-xxxx)"
            workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
          displayName: "Run > terraform apply"
```

Alternatively, According to this **[blog2](https://erwinstaal.nl/posts/manual-approval-in-an-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline/#)** make sure you create one Environment and then add the approval email to yourself or any reviewer, Use this Environment to run your job and then run the `terraform apply` command like below:-

[image]

[image]

And then reference in your yaml job running the terraform task:-

```yaml
- stage: 'terraformstage'
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Deploy'
    environment: 'terraformenv'
    strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
```